# Downloaded files using Selenium and ChromeDriver visible only to the browser

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am using Selenium and Chrome to simulate clicking a button that downloads a PDF file. Everything works as expected, Chrome shows the download as successful, and clicking the file on Chrome opens and displays the file adequately. However, when I try to access the file from a file manager or any other application (including `ls -a` as superuser) the downloaded file just isn't there. Is this done on purpose by Selenium/Chrome? Is there any way to circumvent this?

I'm running Python 3.8.5 on Xubuntu 20.04.2 LTS. Selenium is version 3.141.0 and ChromeDriver is 90.0.4430.212.

This is how I initialize the webdriver:

```python
from tempfile import TemporaryDirectory
from selenium import webdriver

self.tmpdir = TemporaryDirectory()
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_experimental_option("prefs", {
    "download.default_directory":   self.tmpdir.name,
    "download.prompt_for_download": False,
    "download.directory_upgrade":   True,
    "safebrowsing.enabled":         True
    })
options.add_argument('window-size=1366x768')
self.webdriver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
self.webdriver.implicitly_wait(25)
```

Comment: It would be downloaded in project folder which is current root folder during execution. Can you check if it is there.

Comment: Yes I can: the downloaded file does not show up on the project's directory. Opening the PDF in Chrome shows `file:///tmp/[TEMPORARYDIR]/[FILENAME].pdf` in the address bar, which is also not the project's directory.

Comment: Did you check in temp directory ?

Comment: Yes, and that's what is strange to me. The folder created with python's `TemporaryDirectory()` turns out completely empty for `ls -a` and the file managerr, even if the spawned Chrome window tells me the PDF is there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was happening to me when trying to save to directories outside home, changing to save inside home fixed the issue.

The following link clarified the reason:
https://askubuntu.com/questions/1184357/why-cant-chromium-suddenly-access-any-partition-except-for-home